# @Autowired gives me NPE

Tags: java, spring

A source code is

```
public class MailSenzer {
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) { this.mailSender = mailSender; }

public static void send(MailForm mail) {
    new MailSenzer().senz(mail);
}

private void senz(MailForm mail) {
    MimeMessage msger = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

    try {
        MimeMessageHelper msg = new MimeMessageHelper(msger, mail.getEncoding());
        msg.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        msg.setText(mail.getContent(), true);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.getFrom()));
        msg.setTo(new InternetAddress(mail.getTo(), mail.getTo_name(), mail.getEncoding()));

        if(mail.getAttachment() != null) {
            msg.addAttachment(MimeUtility.encodeText(mail.getAttachment_name(), "euc-kr", "B"), mail.getAttachment());
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }

    try {
        mailSender.send(msger);
    } catch(Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
}
```

}

This is the code I wrote. I tested the same code exactly in a controller and it worked, however, when I tried to run as a static method, it gives me error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at kr.co.ubplay.utility.mail.MailSenzer.senz(MailSenzer.java:25)
at kr.co.ubplay.utility.mail.MailSenzer.send(MailSenzer.java:21)
at kr.co.ubplay.service.b2biz.controller.CoopEmailController.coop_send(CoopEmailController.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And the line that has the npe is

```
MimeMessage msger = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
```

I have a common package named com.ubis for scanning, and all of the packages are under that domain.

This is happening with the Custom Tag Library in jsp 2.0. I tried to access a working dao, but that also gave a npe with the autowired sqlSession. Can't figure out what is wrong with these problems :(

Comment: Do your define "mailSender" bean in spring ?

Comment: @jason I did.. But didn't work

Comment: objects created with the `new` keyword will never be autowired by spring.  you need to get the bean from the application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a bean using new then you have to handle it and the same can not be Autowired.

If want to use Autowired then make it spring beans using any annotations.

Comment: This figured me out of how Spring works :) Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 4):

Make `MailSenzer` to be a Spring bean, and `JavaMailSender` will be auto wired. `Spring` will not auto wire beans into objects created with `new` (mentioned by @Affe). Try to build more 'Spring like' system, if you start to use its IoC container :)

```
@Service
public class MailSender {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

// other stuff 

}

public class SomeBusinessLogicClass {

@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

// other stuff

}
```